# Url Changing in php

Tags: php, youtube

Aoa every one i use youtube download master script. In the getvideo file direct links are shown in this format

```
http://r8---sn-a5mekm7l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=80A7B5CE3362C4896F566DA76A8520371D66A2BD.52B2941D336128059CD0A6165A543BDBAFB3CCDC&pl=24&mime=video%2F3gpp&ip=162.213.195.126&ipbits=0&nh=EAU&mm=35&fexp=900718%2C905653%2C907263%2C927622%2C932320%2C936102%2C9405427%2C9406355%2C941004%2C943917%2C947209%2C947225%2C948124%2C948703%2C951500%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C955301%2C957103%2C957105%2C957201%2C959701%2C960900&key=yt5&id=o-AKYJ4H87WlzlVTjFQTbKG2LN6NlZN36MxrlhmNQX4_cP&expire=1421857851&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=G37MNKZ4yl4&itag=17&ms=pm&sver=3&mt=1421832271&mv=s&dur=5973.426&source=youtube
```

but i want in this format

```
https://r5---sn-q4f7sn7l.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?signature=80A7B5CE3362C4896F566DA76A8520371D66A2BD.52B2941D336128059CD0A6165A543BDBAFB3CCDC&pl=24&mime=video%2F3gpp&ip=162.213.195.126&ipbits=0&nh=EAU&mm=35&fexp=900718%2C905653%2C907263%2C927622%2C932320%2C936102%2C9405427%2C9406355%2C941004%2C943917%2C947209%2C947225%2C948124%2C948703%2C951500%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C955301%2C957103%2C957105%2C957201%2C959701%2C960900&key=yt5&id=o-AKYJ4H87WlzlVTjFQTbKG2LN6NlZN36MxrlhmNQX4_cP&expire=1421857851&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=G37MNKZ4yl4&itag=17&ms=pm&sver=3&mt=1421832271&mv=s&dur=5973.426&source=youtube
```

i am not good in php.

thanks in advance

Comment: `i am not good in php`, hmm then i think you want to start learn it! Do you really think we write your code? If you can't write PHP, you will come every day and we should then write ever script for you!?!

Comment: why `docs.google.com`?

Comment: http://r8---sn-a5mekm7l.googlevideo.com is not accessible from here but if i change http://r8---sn-a5mekm7l.googlevideo.com to  https://r5---sn-q4f7sn7l.c.docs.google.com then i get it... that why i want to change it

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `http://r8---sn-a5mekm7l.googlevideo.com/` to `https://r5---sn-q4f7sn7l.c.docs.google.com/` if all video URLs have same initial string you want to replace

Here is code

```
<?php   
$url = str_replace("http://r8---sn-a5mekm7l.googlevideo.com/", 
     "https://r5---sn-q4f7sn7l.c.docs.google.com/", $url);

 echo $url
?>
```

Comment: yes bro rest of link remain same i just want to replace 1st 32 characters

Comment: Ok, did you try my answer?

Comment: @Umair ^ See already the next question! Will you answer OP's question every day? Because you write OP's code, but he don't learn anything!

Comment: @WaqasYounas just copy my answer now